# Loop over object and array of objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, loops

Calling an API i get this data

```
{
    "count":33,
    "results":
        [
            {"id":365,"firstName":"Maisha","lastName":"Rawlings"},
            {"id":613,"firstName":"Lettie","lastName":"Epps"},
            {"id":433,"firstName":"Rocco","lastName":"Gant"},
            {"id":856,"firstName":"Tova","lastName":"Coyle"},
            {"id":896,"firstName":"Tari","lastName":"Mancuso"},
            {"id":79,"firstName":"Tora","lastName":"Prince"},
            {"id":59,"firstName":"Lashon","lastName":"Dunaway"},
            {"id":378,"firstName":"Corey","lastName":"Schaffer"},
            {"id":33,"firstName":"Nanci","lastName":"Middleton"},
            {"id":390,"firstName":"Carmon","lastName":"Lavender"}
        ]
}
```

Which i have it in here for testing purposes
https://mocki.io/v1/d676e413-6659-4410-a8a3-7d5636f4b719

I have the next app made in React

```
const USERS_URL = "https://mocki.io/v1/d676e413-6659-4410-a8a3-7d5636f4b719";

export default function Table() {
    const [names, setNames] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getData() {
        let response = await fetch(`${USERS_URL}`);
        response = await response.json();
        console.log(response);
        setNames(response);
        }
        getData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
        <table className="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {
                    names
                    &&
                    Object.entries(names).map(([key, value, idx]) => {
                        return  <tr key={key}>
                                    <td>{names.key}</td>
                                    <td>{value.results[key]}</td>
                                    {console.log(key, value)}
                                </tr>
                    })
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I can't find the way to loop over "results", which is an array of objects. Any hint please?

Comment: instead of setNames(response); try setNames(response.results);

Comment: And then just `names.map(...)`, instead of `Object.entries(names).map(...)`.

Comment: Check this example https://codesandbox.io/s/example-react-hooks-usestate-forked-rpt3l4 with your code.

Comment: Many thanks guys, that definitely worked.
But what if, for example, i need to store also "count" in the same state? can i do that? or should i create another hook for that?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan ? @T.J.Crowder?

Comment: @Serralvaro, Check this modified example https://codesandbox.io/s/example-react-hooks-usestate-forked-edvjd6

Comment: @ManirajMurugan you're a Master, many thanks for your time and knowledge

Comment: @Serralvaro, Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

> **Sollution**

```
names.results.map((val,index)=>{
console.log("object",val)
})
```

> **us hte . we can access the properties inside and Object  first access the result array in the object and then map() on it**